# Slow map in java

Tags: java, graphics, 2d-games

I'm making a game in java, is a rpg, however, only with the map the game is slow. 
The map is made ​​in TiledMap Editor, therefore, an XML that is read and loaded into an ArrayList. My PC is a dual-core 3.0, 4GB RAM, 1GB Video. 
The do the rendering is done as follows:

```
//method of tileset class
public void loadTileset(){
    positions = new int[1 + tilesX * tilesY][2];
    int yy = 0;
    int xx = 0;
    int index = 0;
    // save the initial x and y point of each tile in an array named positions 
    // positions[tileNumber] [0] - X position 
    // positions[tileNumber] [1] - Y position
    for(int i = 1 ; i < positions.length; i++){ 
        if(index == tilesX ){
            yy += tileHeight;
            xx = 0;
            index = 0;
        }
        positions[i][0] = xx;
        positions[i][1] = yy;
        xx += tileWidth;    
        index++;
    }
}


//method of map class
public void draw(Graphics2D screen){
    //x and y position of each tile on the screen
    int x = 0; int y = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < 20 ; j++){
        for(int i = initialTile ; i < initialTile + quantTiles  ; i++){
            int tile = map[j][i];
            if(tile != 0){
                screen.drawImage(tileSet.getTileImage().getSubimage(tileSet.getTileX(tile), tileSet.getTileY(tile),tileSet.getTileWidth(), tileSet.getTileHeight()),x,y,null);
            }
            x += tileSet.getTileWidth();
        }
        x = 0;
        y += tileSet.getTileHeight();
    }

}
```

Am I doing something wrong? 
Note: I'm new to the forum and to make matters worse I do not understand very much English, so excuse any mistake.

Comment: It's hard to see any obvious errors here. You might want to try a profiler (such as `visualvm` which should be included in the JDK) and use it to find what's taking the most time.

Comment: How often do you redraw the map? What subtype of Image are you using? And finally, both AWT and Swing are slow, consider faster 2D graphics libraries.

Comment: @KarolS AWT and Swing are **NOT** slow. (No offense, just mentioning it...)

Comment: @Marco They are, compared to actual game-oriented libraries. Well, maybe not AWT, I have never used it, but with Swing I noticed enormous performance difference after I redid rendering of the main window in Slick2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not create the subimages for the tiles during each call. Strictly speaking, you should **not** call `getSubimage` at all for images that you want to paint: It will make the image "unmanaged", and this can degrade rendering performance by an order of magnitude. You should only call `getSubimage` for images that you do not want to render - for example, when you are initially creating individual images for the tiles.

You obviously already have a `TileSet` class. You could add a bit of functionality to this class so that you can *directly* access images for the tiles.

Your current code looks like this:

```
screen.drawImage(
    tileSet.getTileImage().getSubimage(
        tileSet.getTileX(tile), 
        tileSet.getTileY(tile),
        tileSet.getTileWidth(), 
        tileSet.getTileHeight()),
    x,y,null);
```

You could change it to look like this:

```
screen.drawImage(tileSet.getTileImage(tile), x,y,null);
```

The `getTileImage(int tile)` method suggested here could then obtain tiles that have been stored internally.

I'll sketch a few lines of code from the tip of my head, you'll probably be able to transfer this into your `TileSet` class:

```
class TileSet
{
    private Map<Integer, BufferedImage> tileImages;

    TileSet()
    {
        ....
        prepareTileImages();
    }

    private void prepareTileImages()
    {
        tileImages = new HashMap<Integer, BufferedImage>();

        for (int tile : allPossibleTileValuesThatMayBeInTheMap)
        {
            // These are the tiles that you originally rendered
            // in your "draw"-Method
            BufferedImage image = 
                getTileImage().getSubimage(
                    getTileX(tile), 
                    getTileY(tile),
                    getTileWidth(), 
                    getTileHeight());

            // Create a new, managed copy of the image,
            // and store it in the map
            BufferedImage managedImage = convertToARGB(image);
            tileImages.put(tile, managedImage);
        }
    }

    private static BufferedImage convertToARGB(BufferedImage image)
    {
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return newImage;
    }    

    // This is the new method: For a given "tile" value
    // that you found at map[x][y], this returns the
    // appropriate tile:
    public BufferedImage getTileImage(int tile) 
    {
        return tileImages.get(tile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll try. Thanks for help

Comment: Greatly improved, even rendering areas that do not appear on the screen slowly stopped. Just a question, do not understand why the method `convertToARGB()`, made ​​as follows: `tileImages.put(index,image.getSubimage(xx, yy, tileWidth, tileHeight);`. What is the purpose of the method previously mentioned?

Comment: @Cairo I wrote a few words about that in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22231370/3182664 , further information is e.g. at http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/managed_images.html

Comment: Ok, thnks for help @Marco13